# How can I list all files checked in by me in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: version-control, tfs

How can I list the last `x` files I checked in to TFS?

Comment: Added the full name of the application for future Google searches.

Answer (score 3):

Using the TFS PS Snapin included with the TFS PowerToys<sup>1</sup>...

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/" -recurse -stop 50 -user "my-username" | % { Get-TfsChangeset $_.Changesetid} |select -expand changes | select -first 20
```

The `-stop 50` in the first stage is to avoid every change ever being retrieved which will slow things down with a significant repository. Also note, this does not eliminate duplicates where the same file is part of multiple changesets.

<sup>1</sup> Information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2008/10/01/preview-of-the-next-tfs-power-tools-release.aspx), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2008/11/08/oct-08-tfs-power-tools-are-available.aspx) and [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en). Use the custom install to add the PSSnapin.

Answer (score 3):

tf history /user:myusername /stopafter:10 /recursive /noprompt $/

Answer (score 2):

Install [Team Foudation SideKick](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/), you will have a lot of filter to search what you want inside TFS.

Answer (score 1):

In Source Code explorer, right click on the project and click View History.

Comment: There's no "View History" for projects, I'm using VS2012

Answer (score 0):

Login to your TFS server's web site and look at the changesets.