# TFS View History for specifc User

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2010 and am wondering whether there is an easy way, either through the IDE (or via the command line), to view the check-in history for a given user, filtered by time.  Basically, I would like to see a list of all the changesets for a given user (or simply current user) and be able to specify a date range.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797941/how-can-i-list-all-files-checked-in-by-me-in-team-foundation-server

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118277/list-all-files-checked-into-tfs-by-a-user-in-past-few-days

Comment: Although the questions are similar, the answers don't show how to filter by a date interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command prompt you can use 'tf hist' passing the user name and date interval as parameters.

```
tf hist path /user:username /version:D06/01/2012~D06/30/2012
```

More info about **tf history** can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx

More info about defining Version Specs can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be.aspx

The Version Spec is the part that defines the filter to be applied.

Comment: Alfred, thanks for leading me down the right path.  The date format requires quotes and the /recursive switch was needed to get at what I wanted, the full code being as follows: `tf hist $ /user:username /version:"D06/01/2012"~"D06/30/2012" /recursive /login:username,password /noprompt`